# itemId on TabPanel's tabs is being "deleted" by the framework?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm trying to fiddle around with the stock application that SenchaCmd 6 produces when doing a `sencha app generate` and I'm adding click events on the side menu tabs as such:

```
Ext.define('UserManager.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',
    ...
    listeners: { 
    render: 'onMenuRender'
    }
});
```

The onMenuRender method in the controller:

```
onMenuRender: function (tabPanel, a) {
    tabPanel.items.each(function(item) {
        item.tab.on('click', this.onTabItemClick);
    }, this);
}
```

onTabItemClick:

```
onTabItemClick: function(tabItem, a) {
    alert(tabItem.itemId);
}
```

The issue is that `itemId` or whatever member variable I'm assigning a value to in the view config is not available once in the controller and is always `undefined`

Here's an example tab:

```
{
    title: 'Users',
    itemId: 'usersTab',
    iconCls: 'fa-user',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'mainlist'
    }]
}
```

What am I missing ? To differentiate from which item was clicked, I don't want to use `id` since this is auto generated by the framework, nor `title` since the text in there can change when supporting many languages.

Comment: What is the value of `tabItem.xtype`? is it `mainlist`?

Comment: @CD.. It's `tab` (Ext.tab.Tab)

Comment: Have you tried using the `tabchange` event? like: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/101j

Comment: That works. Didn't see `tabchange` in the V6 docs and thought it was gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll may want to use the [`tabchange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-event-tabchange) event instead.

> Fires when a new tab has been activated

A working example (with `itemId`): https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/101j